# JQuery UI Autocomplete, how to go over other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I have tried two methods:

```html
<div id = "team-search-container">
    <label for="team-search" class = "text-center">
         <input type = "text" id = "team-search">
    </label>
</div>
```

If I do this:

```js
$( "#team-search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: teamdata,
    appendTo: '#team-search-container'
});
```

It will expand the div to show the elements, like this:
[image: Image for Description]
(Ignore where it says ComboBox elements, I meant to write Autocomplete elements)

But if I do something like this, without the `appendTo` option,

```js
$( "#team-search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: teamdata
});
```

It will work fine, but at the end of the `body`, it will make the empty space equivalent to the height of the autocomplete. Here is my CSS:

```css
.ui-autocomplete{
    position: relative;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.ui-autocomplete-category{
    font-size: 18px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
}

.ui-menu-item{
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #565656;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    display: none;
}
```

So since I have a `max-height` of `600px`, it will create `600px` of empty space at the bottom of the page if I don't append it to anything, even though it shows the autocomplete right under my search bar.

Comment: What is `catcomplete`? Also, what is your actual question/goal? I think you are saying you don't want to use `appendTo`, just use the normal dropdown. If so, that works by default out of the box.  You don't need any extra CSS, [check the examples in the docs](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).  If this doesn't help, pls edit your question and try to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Please read the JQuery UI Docs before commenting. `catcomplete` a part of their library.

Comment: @Dragonsnap the widget `catcomplete` is not a part of the jQuery UI library: https://jqueryui.com/?s=catcomplete Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

With the example you have provided, I have been unable to replicate the issue as you described it. Please review:

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        if (item.category) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  
  var data = [{
      label: "anders",
      category: ""
    },
    {
      label: "andreas",
      category: ""
    },
    {
      label: "antal",
      category: ""
    },
    {
      label: "annhhx10",
      category: "Products"
    },
    {
      label: "annk K12",
      category: "Products"
    },
    {
      label: "annttop C13",
      category: "Products"
    },
    {
      label: "anders andersson",
      category: "People"
    },
    {
      label: "andreas andersson",
      category: "People"
    },
    {
      label: "andreas johnson",
      category: "People"
    }
  ];

  $("#team-search").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    appendTo: '#team-search-container'
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.ui-autocomplete-category {
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
}

.ui-menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #565656;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="team-search-container">
  <label for="team-search" class="text-center"><input type = "text" id = "team-search" /> </label>
</div>
```

Data and Categories are loading as expected. If you need further assistance, please review your code, check for any Console errors, and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your example did not include any sample data.